# detect an singleton object has been initialised before

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to tell that [MyClass sharedInstance] has been called before and is not nil?
I need to tell if another class has already initialised the singleton without actually initialising the singleton object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best option would be to add a class method along with the `sharedInstance` method that returns a `BOOL` and indicates whether the singleton exists or not.

Comment: in order to do that, you will have to call [MyClass singleton].isReady, right? which also inits the object?

Comment: No. I said a class method, not an instance method.